# Application missing from Settings > Apps > Running

Tags: android-emulator

After deploying an application in the Android emulator (I'm targeting Android 4.1.2 - API Level 16) and running it:

- the application is **not** displayed in the Settings > Apps > Running list
- the application is displayed when holding the home button for a long time
- the application process is listed by the "ps" command (ran from ADB)

Is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: It is normal if the application has been started and then closed instantly!

Comment: Not only "instantly". Long-holding the home button shows "recently **started**" apps, which are not necessarily "currently running". Check the processes list with either `ps` in a terminal emulator, or some process listing app, to see whether it is really running.

Comment: Well the thing is that the "ps" command indeed shows that the application is running (I edited my question to mention that). In fact, I know that it's running... since I can see it on the emulator screen !